# Yosemite Finder Window: See Item count/selection and available size

Tags: ios, macos, finder

I’ve just upgraded to Yosemite (10.10.2) and would love to know if anyone can help me figure out how to make my finder window display a line at the bottom letting me know how many files i have in each given folder as well as remaining space left in my mac (like i used to have with version 10.9.5).

I know about the command+shift+i, but was wondering if there was this more fixed way of having that info always hanging out on my finder window!

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 4):

To show this information in Yosemite, do the following:

1. Open a Finder window
2. Go to the **View** menu -> Show Status Bar
3. Information should now appear at the bottom of the window.

Alternatively,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>  will toggle it on/off.

Comment: It also works same way on Mavericks :)

Comment: Works on MacOS Mojave as well :)